# Import a .dat file from CDC mortality 2003 into Rstudio

Tags: r, import, dataset

Greeting stackoverflow R community;
I have downloaded 10 data sets from CDC that correspond to mortality from 2003 to 2013. Each year is a separate data set. Some data sets have an extension of .DUSMCPUB and others have an extension of .dat. I have found a python script on github to parse 2013 .DUSMCPUB file and export it to .csv. However, I have not found anything to read the .dat files. I'm playing around and changing parameters with the `data <- read.table(file = 'Mort03us.dat', header =TRUE, sep = ',')`. When I open the .dat file in a text editor I get this outcome.

[image]

I'm expecting headers on this data. However, I did read the documentation to see if the position of the values make any sense with the documentation, and doesn't.
I search the CDC website hoping to find documentation on how to read the file, or from what software this file was exported, or some information that might help to read the file, but no documentation I found.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664075/import-dat-file-into-r) I found a similar question, however, my .dat is not text and the script is not working for me. Also, I played around with the script without success.

Anyone of you have worked with CDC data sets in .dat format that can give me some guidance on how to import this data into RStudio?

---

## July 1st, 2016:

#### Solution to this question:

I want to make an update to my question. I found a solution and I want to share with the community. Finally, I tweak a python script from github. I was able to parse the .dat file and import the data set into R. I want to thank you all!!

```
fileObj = open('Mort03us.dat', 'r')
fileOutObj = open('mort_2003.csv', 'a')

fileOutObj.write('Resident_Status, Education, Month_Of_Death, Sex, Age_Key, Age_Value, Age_Sub_Flag, Age_Recode_52, ' +
             'Age_Recode_27, Age_Recode_12, Infant_Age_Recode_22, Place_Of_Death, Marital_Status, DOW_of_Death, ' +
             'Data_Year, Injured_At_Work, Manner_Of_Death, Method_Of_Disposition, Autopsy, Activity_Code, ' +
             'Place_Of_Causal_Injury, ICD10, Cause_Recode_358, Cause_Recode_113, Infant_Cause_Recode_130, ' +
             'Cause_Recode_39, Entity_Axis_Conditions, EAC1, EAC2, EAC3, EAC4, EAC5, EAC6, EAC7, EAC8, EAC9, ' +
             'EAC10, EAC11, EAC12, EAC13, EAC14, EAC15, EAC16, EAC17, EAC18, EAC19, EAC20, '
             'Record_Axis_Conditions, RA1, RA2, RA3, RA4, RA5, RA6, RA7, RA8, RA9, RA10, RA11, RA12, RA13, RA14, ' +
             'RA15, RA16, RA17, RA18, RA19, RA20, Race, Race_Bridged, Race_Imputation, Race_Recode_3, ' +
             'Race_Recode_5, Hispanic_Origin, Hispanic_Origin_Recode\n')

outStr = ''

for line in fileObj:
    Resident_Status = line[19].strip()
    Education = line[60:62].strip()
    Month_Of_Death = line[64:66].strip()
    Sex = line[68].strip()
    Age_Key = line[69].strip()
    Age_Value = line[70:73].strip()
    Age_Sub_Flag = line[73].strip()
    Age_Recode_52 = line[74:76].strip()
    Age_Recode_27 = line[76:78].strip()
    Age_Recode_12 = line[78:80].strip()
    Infant_Age_Recode_22 = line[80:82].strip()
    Place_Of_Death = line[82].strip()
    Marital_Status = line[83].strip()
    DOW_of_Death = line[84].strip()
    Data_Year = line[101:105].strip()
    Injured_At_Work = line[105].strip()
    Manner_Of_Death = line[106].strip()
    Method_Of_Disposition = line[107].strip()
    Autopsy = line[108].strip()
    Activity_Code = line[143].strip()
    Place_Of_Causal_Injury = line[144].strip()
    ICD10 = line[145:149].strip()
    Cause_Recode_358 = line[149:152].strip()
    Cause_Recode_113 = line[153:156].strip()
    Infant_Cause_Recode_130 = line[156:159].strip()
    Cause_Recode_39 = line[159:161].strip()
    Entity_Axis_Conditions = line[162:164].strip()
    EAC1 = line[164:171].strip()
    EAC2 = line[171:178].strip()
    EAC3 = line[178:185].strip()
    EAC4 = line[185:192].strip()
    EAC5 = line[192:199].strip()
    EAC6 = line[199:206].strip()
    EAC7 = line[206:213].strip()
    EAC8 = line[213:220].strip()
    EAC9 = line[220:227].strip()
    EAC10 = line[227:234].strip()
    EAC11 = line[234:241].strip()
    EAC12 = line[241:248].strip()
    EAC13 = line[248:255].strip()
    EAC14 = line[255:262].strip()
    EAC15 = line[262:269].strip()
    EAC16 = line[269:276].strip()
    EAC17 = line[276:283].strip()
    EAC18 = line[283:290].strip()
    EAC19 = line[290:297].strip()
    EAC20 = line[297:304].strip()
    Record_Axis_Conditions = line[340:342]
    RA1 = line[343:348].strip()
    RA2 = line[348:353].strip()
    RA3 = line[353:358].strip()
    RA4 = line[358:363].strip()
    RA5 = line[363:368].strip()
    RA6 = line[368:373].strip()
    RA7 = line[373:378].strip()
    RA8 = line[378:383].strip()
    RA9 = line[383:388].strip()
    RA10 = line[388:393].strip()
    RA11 = line[393:398].strip()
    RA12 = line[398:403].strip()
    RA13 = line[403:408].strip()
    RA14 = line[408:413].strip()
    RA15 = line[413:418].strip()
    RA16 = line[418:423].strip()
    RA17 = line[423:428].strip()
    RA18 = line[428:433].strip()
    RA19 = line[433:438].strip()
    RA20 = line[438:443].strip()
    Race = line[444:446].strip()
    Race_Bridged = line[446].strip()
    Race_Imputation = line[447].strip()
    Race_Recode_3 = line[448].strip()
    Race_Recode_5 = line[449].strip()
    Hispanic_Origin = line[483:486].strip()
    Hispanic_Origin_Recode = line[487].strip()
      
    outStr = (Resident_Status + ', ' + Education + ', ' + Month_Of_Death + ', ' + Sex +
          ', ' + Age_Key + ', ' + Age_Value + ', ' + Age_Sub_Flag + ', ' + Age_Recode_52 +
          ', ' + Age_Recode_27 + ', ' + Age_Recode_12 + ', ' + Infant_Age_Recode_22 + ', ' + Place_Of_Death +
          ', ' + Marital_Status + ', ' + DOW_of_Death + ', ' + Data_Year + ', ' + Injured_At_Work +
          ', ' + Manner_Of_Death + ', ' + Method_Of_Disposition + ', ' + Autopsy + ', ' + Activity_Code +
          ', ' + Place_Of_Causal_Injury + ', ' + ICD10 + ', ' + Cause_Recode_358 + ', ' + Cause_Recode_113 +
          ', ' + Infant_Cause_Recode_130 + ', ' + Cause_Recode_39 + ', ' + Entity_Axis_Conditions + ', ' + EAC1 +
          ', ' + EAC2 + ', ' + EAC3 + ', ' + EAC4 + ', ' + EAC5 +
          ', ' + EAC6 + ', ' + EAC7 + ', ' + EAC8 + ', ' + EAC9 +
          ', ' + EAC10 + ', ' + EAC11 + ', ' + EAC12 + ', ' + EAC13 +
          ', ' + EAC14 + ', ' + EAC15 + ', ' + EAC16 + ', ' + EAC17 +
          ', ' + EAC18 + ', ' + EAC19 + ', ' + EAC20 + ', ' + Record_Axis_Conditions +
          ', ' + RA1 + ', ' + RA2 + ', ' + RA3 + ', ' + RA4 +
          ', ' + RA5 + ', ' + RA6 + ', ' + RA7 + ', ' + RA8 +
          ', ' + RA9 + ', ' + RA10 + ', ' + RA11 + ', ' + RA12 +
          ', ' + RA13 + ', ' + RA14 + ', ' + RA15 + ', ' + RA16 +
          ', ' + RA17 + ', ' + RA18 + ', ' + RA19 + ', ' + RA20 +
          ', ' + Race + ', ' + Race_Bridged + ', ' + Race_Imputation + ', ' + Race_Recode_3 +
          ', ' + Race_Recode_5 + ', ' + Hispanic_Origin + ', ' + Hispanic_Origin_Recode + '\n')

fileOutObj.write(outStr)

print("Parse complete.")
fileOutObj.close()
fileObj.close()
```

This code will work with Python 3.

Comment: Can you post a small part of your file or a link to it? The picture didn't help

Comment: That image of your .dat file looks like all text to me, in which case either `read.fwf` or some form of regular expressions should be able to import it.

Comment: The link is [here](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data_access/vitalstatsonline.htm#Mortality_Multiple). Please notice that you want the **Mortality Multiple Cause Files**. Please download the 2003 zip file. @r2evans - I have work with CDC data before, and this image doesn't show the way CDC normally build data sets.

Comment: You asked about *this* file you are showing, and as I just downloaded it, the file *is* text (`Mort03ps.dat: ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators`). Read `?read.fwf`. (Or provide information on a differently-formatted file.)

Comment: The file is not Mort03ps.dat. It is Mort03us.dat instead. I don't know if the one you download has the same format as the other one.

Comment: OK, 88MB took a few minutes to download (and I apologize for not verifying the filename). Still text: `Mort03us.dat: ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators`. Same basic format (haven't compared the minutia), still parse-able. Have you tried `read.fwf` and it chokes on something, or are you hoping somebody will come up with a magic pill for you?

Comment: @r2evans - No, I'm not waiting for somebody to come with a magic pill for me.

Comment: You can get a CSV through [WONDER](http://wonder.cdc.gov/mcd-icd10.html)

Comment: @alistaire - It is awesome to get a data set. However, variables are missing getting the data this way. Manner of death is missing.

Comment: Some of that is baked into ICD-10. Regardless, [NBER has already done your work for you](http://www.nber.org/data/multicause.html)

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the file extension, it's merely a text file (88MB, with 2.4M rows). On inspection, it looks fixed-width (at 430 chars wide, a bit wide to show here, though your picture does it justice).

The only "trick" to reading in FWF files is to find the column widths. In some "dat" files, this is well-defined/documented, but it can often be inferred by looking at the first few lines. In this case, I just counted characters. (I only grab the first 100 lines for brevity.)

Some of the fields appear to be space-delimited. That is, some (even most) of the rows had a space between two groupings but some rows had none. Since I don't know how to decode the logic, I keep those together (with the space). (Namely: `V6`, `V8`, and `V9`.)

```
mort <- read.fwf("~/Downloads/foo/Mort03us.dat",
                 widths = c(30, 26, 6, 4, 7, 12, 24, 43, 9, 178, 3, 100, 4, 4, 36, 2),
                 header = FALSE, n = 100, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(mort)
# 'data.frame': 100 obs. of  16 variables:
#  $ V1 : chr  "                  11AK999AK9AK" "                  11AK999AK9AK" "                  11AK999AK9AK" "                  11AK999AK9AK" ...
#  $ V2 : chr  "  AK9999999992AK00009900OR" "  AK9999999992AK00009900NY" "  AK9999999992AK00009900WA" "  AK9999999992AK00009900TX" ...
#  $ V3 : chr  "  OR14" "  NY17" "  WA15" "  TX16" ...
#  $ V4 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ V5 : chr  "  F1079" "  F1088" "  F1059" "  F1084" ...
#  $ V6 : chr  " 412110  4W4" " 432311  1W6" " 371708  6D7" " 422210  4W7" ...
#  $ V7 : chr  "                2003U7UN" "                2003U7UN" "                2003U7UN" "                2003U7UN" ...
#  $ V8 : chr  "                                    I361226" "                                    I499228" "                                    C64 117" "                                    C349093" ...
#  $ V9 : chr  " 068   22" " 068   22" " 034   12" " 027   08" ...
#  $ V10: chr  " 0711I500 21I361 31I10  61I679 62I739 63M199 64N289                                                                            "| __truncated__ " 0311R568 21I959 31I499                                                                                                        "| __truncated__ " 0111C64                                                                                                                       "| __truncated__ " 0111C349                                                                                                                      "| __truncated__ ...
#  $ V11: int  7 3 1 1 2 3 4 4 1 1 ...
#  $ V12: chr  " I10  I361 I500 I679 I739 M199 N289                                                                 " " I499 I959 R568                                                                                     " " C64                                                                                                " " C349                                                                                               " ...
#  $ V13: int  1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ V14: int  11 11 11 23 23 11 11 11 11 11 ...
#  $ V15: int  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 ...
#  $ V16: int  6 6 6 8 8 6 6 6 6 6 ...
```

There is a lot of white-space, and the `read.fwf` function doesn't automatically remove it for you, so we'll have to take care of that next.

```
# chars <- sapply(mort, is.character)
mort[,chars] <- sapply(mort[,chars], function(z) {
  gsub("[[:space:]]+", " ", trimws(z))
}, simplify = FALSE)
str(mort)
# 'data.frame': 100 obs. of  16 variables:
#  $ V1 : chr  "11AK999AK9AK" "11AK999AK9AK" "11AK999AK9AK" "11AK999AK9AK" ...
#  $ V2 : chr  "AK9999999992AK00009900OR" "AK9999999992AK00009900NY" "AK9999999992AK00009900WA" "AK9999999992AK00009900TX" ...
#  $ V3 : chr  "OR14" "NY17" "WA15" "TX16" ...
#  $ V4 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ V5 : chr  "F1079" "F1088" "F1059" "F1084" ...
#  $ V6 : chr  "412110 4W4" "432311 1W6" "371708 6D7" "422210 4W7" ...
#  $ V7 : chr  "2003U7UN" "2003U7UN" "2003U7UN" "2003U7UN" ...
#  $ V8 : chr  "I361226" "I499228" "C64 117" "C349093" ...
#  $ V9 : chr  "068 22" "068 22" "034 12" "027 08" ...
#  $ V10: chr  "0711I500 21I361 31I10 61I679 62I739 63M199 64N289" "0311R568 21I959 31I499" "0111C64" "0111C349" ...
#  $ V11: int  7 3 1 1 2 3 4 4 1 1 ...
#  $ V12: chr  "I10 I361 I500 I679 I739 M199 N289" "I499 I959 R568" "C64" "C349" ...
#  $ V13: int  1 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ V14: int  11 11 11 23 23 11 11 11 11 11 ...
#  $ V15: int  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 ...
#  $ V16: int  6 6 6 8 8 6 6 6 6 6 ...
```

The last bit to take into account is that some of the uber-wide fields (`V10` and `V12`) appear to be variable lists of codes. Since I wasn't confident I knew exactly *how many*, etc, I chose to keep them together, too. (This would be a good time to learn something about some more of Hadley's packages, specifically [`broom`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/index.html) and [`purrr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/index.html). [This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz3_FDVt9eg) is an hour of Hadley talking about nested dataframes using these packages.)

(For the record, it does take a while to load the whole file and do this processing, so be patient. My recommendation is to "practice" on a modest subset of the entire file to make sure your processing is doing what you want. When you have your steps mapped out and tested, then run them all and go get a coffee.)

Comment: You need to understand what the data means before you do what you did. Base on documentation, the first 18 blank spaces or positions are reserved positions. `$V1 = "11AK999AK9AK"`, which is 12 char long, 1st position `1` means Record Type. 2nd `1` means Resident status. The 3rd and 4th position `AK` is the state of occurrence. The entire string is not one value. I cannot import the data the way you did it. There are some positions that are empty for some observations but with data for other observations. The data needs to be parsed before importing into R.

Comment: probably just need to adjust the field widths (i.e. split the initial 30-character field into something like 19 (18 white spaces + 1st position [record type]), 1 (resident status), 2 (state), 3 (?), 2 (State again), 1 (?), 2 (state again).

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker, yes that was the intent: show how to do the basic import so that Gilbert could change it as needed based on the format of the file. I was confident that some of my assumptions were wrong, but then again, once you know what is wrong and how it was done, correcting it should be fairly easy.

Comment: I'm working on a python script to parse the entire .dat file before importing into R. As English is not my 1st language, probably I was not clear in my question. I was hoping for anyone of you knew about a script to parse the .dat file. I'm almost done though. I will post my work for helping others.

Comment: I have no problem with your English. I'm confused by the fact that you asked for a solution *in R*, I provided one that is **easily** adjusted to account for different column widths, @alistaire suggested a site that has already-parsed CSVs, and yet you discount all of it. Do what you will.

Comment: I didn't ask specific for R solution. I mention the python script that I found that parsed 2013 data set. I was having problems to import the .dat file since the script didn't parse correctly. I finally got the python script to work and I will post the code here to help others.

Comment: You tagged this with `[r]`. You opened your question with *"Greeting stackoverflow R community"*. You said you needed help with `data <- read.table(file...` (which is R code). And yet you say you didn't want an R solution? I'm out.